# Reading BigQuery federated table as source in Dataflow throws an error

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a federated source in BigQuery which is pointing to some CSV files in GCS.

When I try to read to the federated BigQuery table as a source for a Dataflow pipeline, it throws the following error:

```
    1226 [main] ERROR com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableRowIterator  - Error reading from BigQuery table Federated_test_dataflow of dataset CPT_7414_PLAYGROUND : 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Cannot list a table of type EXTERNAL.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Cannot list a table of type EXTERNAL."
}
```

Does Dataflow not support federated sources in BigQuery, or am I doing something wrong? I do know that I could read the files from GCS directly into my pipeline, but I'd prefer to work with BigQuery `TableRow` objects instead due to the design of the application.

```
 PCollection<TableRow> results = pipeline.apply("fed-test", BigQueryIO.Read.from("<project_id>:CPT_7414_PLAYGROUND.Federated_test_dataflow")).apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            System.out.println(c.element());
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Which runner are you using? The `DirectPipelineRunner`, the `DataflowPipelineRunner` or the `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner`?

Comment: DirectPipelineRunner

Comment: @polleyg We've added another answer, if it helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Michael says, BigQuery does not support directly reading from EXTERNAL (federated tables) or VIEWs: even reading effectively takes a query.

To read from these tables in Dataflow, you can instead use

```
BigQueryIO.Read.fromQuery("SELECT * FROM table_or_view_name")
```

which will issue the query and save the result to a temporary table, and then begin the read process. Of course, this will incur the costs of querying on BigQuery, so if you wish to read from the same VIEW or EXTERNAL table repeatedly you may want to manually create the table.

Answer (score 5):

The Dataflow BigQuery source was designed to read BigQuery managed tables of type "TABLE". (The type definition can be found at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#type.) EXTERNAL and VIEW tables are not supported.

The BigQuery "federated table" feature allows bigquery to directly query data in places like Google Cloud Storage. Dataflow can also read files from Google Cloud Storage, so you should be able to point your Dataflow computation directly at the sources you want to read.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that Dataflow does not support reading views or federated sources from BigQuery? Correct, like I said in my post I know that I can read from GCS directly but I'd like to be able to keep the design of the application consistent and work with BigQuery TableRow.

Comment: This is not really a fundamental Dataflow issue: it's a (very reasonable) limitation of BigQuery's APIs. I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-174 to make the Dataflow warning show up better. While we could automatically turn the `from(table)` command into a `fromQuery("select * from table")` command we chose not to so that users knowingly opt into the query cost.

Comment: I'd like to disagree with the assertion that this is a "reasonable limitation of BigQuery's APIs". We've just encountered this problem in two ways. First, views a mechanism of encapsulation; they allows us to maintain logic in one place thus adhering to the DRY principle, by embedding a SQL statement inside a Dataflow job we invalidate DRY. Second, we use BigQuery authorised views to govern access to data - in this circumstance we are mandated to use a view and not being able to refer to such a view in a Dataflow job is a blocker for us.